# Need help with Laplace transform of piecewise /step functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate the laplace transform for $f(t)$ where

$$f(t)= \begin{cases}
e^{4t} & \text{if $ 0 \lt t \lt  2 $} \\
1 & \text{if $ t \gt 2 $} \end{cases}$$

( I was a bit confused on what happens at $t=2$ though

Here is what I have thought I could maybe try starting at,

we could write $f(t)=e^{4t}+g(t)$

where $$g(t)= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $0 \lt t \lt 2 $} \\
(1-e^{4t}) & \text{if $t \gt 2$} \end{cases}$$

But now I am confused, because I don't know how I can write g(t) by using the unit step function at 2 , because I don't see how I could get the second part in that form

ie, even if $$g(t)=u_2(t)(1-e^{4t})$$

then I am not sure I understand how I can use the laplace transform on this , because I was only under the impression that we needed it to be of the form $$u_c(t)(f(t-c))$$ in order to use the form $$L[u_c(t)(f(t-c))]=e^{-ct}L[f(t)]$$

Does anyone see where I am getting confused, or what I should do?

Thanks a lot

Comment: check your orginal functon, You have two different assignments for $t$  for $t>0$

Comment: I know that i.e. that I will have to calculate the laplace of the whole thing but I can't do that if I don't know how to do this part

Comment: Then please specify correctly what your function is.

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake, thanks

Comment: Just do it from scratch: $\int_{0}^{2}e^{-st}e^{4t}dt+\int_{2}^{\infty }e^{-st}dt$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the laplace transform of $f$ is 
$$\begin{align} \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt &= \int_0^2e^{(4-s)t} \, dt + \int_2^\infty e^{-st} \, dt\\
&= \frac1{(4-s)}e^{(4-s)t}\big|_0^2-\frac1se^{-st}\big|_2^\infty\\
&= \frac1{(4-s)}\left(e^{8-2s}-1\right) + \frac1se^{-2s}  \end{align}$$